# Pentaho binary presentation to transactional data

Tags: csv, transform, pentaho

I'd like to transform data from a CSV file, like this

```
ID  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   
3   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
```

into a CSV file like this

```
ID  Item
1   5
1   7
2   1
2   3
2   5
3   5
3   6
```

How to transform that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data with a `CSV file input`, then pivot with `Row Normalizer` around the ID column, and `Filter the rows` with Item=0, and put the result in a `Text output file` with a CSV format.

The only challenging part may be the definition of the normalizer [image].

The `Row filter` is straightforward. If it is the first time you use it, note that if you specify a `send true data to step` you must also specify a `send false data to step`. In your case do not specify any, so only true data fill flow through.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i don't know if there is filter row. I've got an idea how to use row normaliser but i don't know how to clean the 0 item.

Comment: I've added the `Filter row`.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to read, the [Official StartUp guide](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0J0/0C0) : `Introduction to transformations`.

You also can get a hand on the kettle book: `Pentaho Kettle Solutions: Building Open Source ETL Solutions with Pentaho Data Integration`by M. Casters, R. Bouman, J. van Dongen. It is a huge and heavy book, but exhaustive and not yet outdated.

You may also have a look into the sample directory which was shipped with your distribution. It contains working examples for almost any steps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know where to study kettle.
I'll note your suggestion. thanks a lot.